# Web Service soap

Tags: java, spring, web-services, soap

I try to call a SOAP web service but I can't do it without a controller class. This is my code in a class named `webService2`, I get a `NullPointerException` when the response is executed.

```
@Service @Transactional public class webService2 {
     @Autowired
     WebServiceTemplate  webservicetemplate2;
     public com.educanet.bbb.ws.user.User get(String username) {
         System.out.println("username is :"+username);
         ListuserbyUsernameUniqueRequest request1000 = new ListuserbyUsernameUniqueRequest();
         request1000.setUsername(username);
         ListuserbyUsernameUniqueResponse resp1000 =  (ListuserbyUsernameUniqueResponse) webservicetemplate2.marshalSendAndReceive(request1000);
         //ListuserbyUsernameUniqueResponse response1000 = (ListuserbyUsernameUniqueResponse) webservicetemplate2.marshalSendAndReceive(request1000);
         System.out.println("iciiiiiiiiiiiiiii");
         com.educanet.bbb.ws.user.User domainUser =    resp1000.getUser();
         return domainUser;
     }   
}
```

Comment: Please provide the stacktrace

Comment: Either, the username is null, @Autowired did not work because your Spring Configuration does not work or there is a bug in the method marshalSendAndReceive(...)

Comment: no im sure about username is not null. when i use this service in my controller class it is fonctionnel but if i try to use it in another place i can't !!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)